# Name variables dynamically

Tags: c, variables

I am creating n threads. I would like to create n variables b1,b2,b3,.,bi,..bn.
How can I do this in C? I mean to choose the name of the global variable according to the number of the thread.

thanks

Comment: You can't.  Variable names only exist at compile time, while threads only exist at runtime.  As others have said, you can get a similar effect by using an array with one element per thread instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6064873/dynamic-variable-declaration-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from *[NapoleonBlownapart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/886232/napoleonblownapart)*'s comment to the OP: "*You can't. Variable names only exist at compile time, while threads only exist at runtime.*"

Use an array, with as much elements as you have threads. Then use the thread's number as index to the arrary

See some pseudo code below:

```
#define THREAD_MAXIMUM (42)

int b[THREAD_MAXIMUM];


thread_func(void * pv)
{
  size_t i = (size_t) pv;

  int bi = b[i];
  ...
}

int main()
{
  ...

  for(size_t i = 0; i < THREAD_MAXIMUM; ++i)
  {
     b[i] = some thread specific number;
     create-thread(thread_func, i) /* create thread and pass index to array element);
  }

  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with arrays or vectors(in C++). I would have preferred coding in C++ and use vector instead of C and array.

Simple implementation with array can be as follows -

```
#define MAX_THREAD(100)

int var[MAX_THREAD]

ThreadImpl(Params)
{
 int i = (int) Params;

 int vari = var[i];
}

int main()
{
  for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; ++i)
  {
    var[i] = val; (val can be ThreadID or other value as per requirement)     
    pthread_create(ThreadImpl, ... other params);
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are no vectors in C. ;)

Comment: OOPS... I thought C++ :). Please see modified answer. Thanks for letting me know. @Devolus